# How to prevent focus loss from an element on an Android long press?

Tags: javascript, android, html, reactjs

I am working on an android app that is primarily web based and have come across an issue with handling Android long presses on a web browser. The problem can be boiled down to the simple example given by the code and JS bin link below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <input/> 
        <canvas
          onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
          onTouchStart={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
          onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
          width="300px"
          height="300px"
          style={{background: 'red'}}
         />
       </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Example](https://jsbin.com/wezuvayugu/1/edit?js,output)

The issue is trying to prevent focus loss from the input when long pressing on the canvas. In order to see the issue, you must view the JS Bin example on a android mobile device. Press the input element so that it is focused, then long press the canvas element. The focus is then lost from the input even though a preventDefault() method is called on the context menu handler. The touch start and mouse down handlers both prevent focus loss correctly with the preventDefault() method but context menu does not.

Currently there are two solutions that I can think of. One is to put the focus back to the input element in the context menu handler and prevent any blur / focus handlers from executing. The other solution is to completely disable long presses on the web view. Both feel like workarounds / hacks than actual solutions as the root problem is the focus loss from the input element. I don't know whether the focus change occurs on the Android side or on the web side which is why I am posting this question.

So far I have tried CSS solutions and JS event listeners to stop the event but they didn't work. I haven't tried solutions on the Android / Java side yet as I primarily work on the web side and would like to exhaust all options before moving on.

If anyone could get a solution to work for me with the JS Bin provided that would be ideal but I would also accept any answer that leads me towards more information for a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was on the Android / Java side. I had to override the onLongClick() method for the webView to avoid losing focus. Below is the code for the solution:

```
// if the result type of the long click is null or not editable text - return true (ignore the long click)
// otherwise return false (show context menu)
_webView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    WebView.HitTestResult result = _webView.getHitTestResult();

    return result == null || result.getType() != WebView.HitTestResult.EDIT_TEXT_TYPE;
  }
});
```